# Android - How to turn off home/back/recent apps buttons light on Google Pixel 2

Tags: java, android

I want to turn off keys(home, back, recent apps) lights on the activity. Here is my code.

```
Settings.System.putInt(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), "button_key_light", 0);
```

It works well on Samsung phone, but it doesn't work on other devices such as Google Pixel 2.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved myself. It works well.

```
private void disableHomebutton() {
    final int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE;

    mainView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

    mainView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
            mainView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        }
    });


    mHomeKeyLocker.lock(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-:

```
@Override  
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  
{  
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)  
    {  
        Log.d("Test", "Back button pressed!");  
    }  
    else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)  
    {  
        Log.d("Test", "Home button pressed!");  
    }  
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by using Immersive Full-Screen Mode.

https://github.com/superdev0714/DisableHome.java/blob/master/DisableHome.java